# Nuget and C++ PDB

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, pdb-files

I am creating my own C++ nuget package for a static library that i compile (with /Zi). I added the .pdb of the library to the nuget package, alongside the .lib, but i can't include it while building the application. I get this linker error:

> Warning LNK4204: 'xxx\Release\vc110.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info

How can I instruct VisualStudio, trought the .targets or .props file released with nuget, where it should find the .pdb?

Obviously, the path embedded in the .lib does not exist on my machine.

Is compiling the static library with /Z7 the only option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can see that: [Linker Tools Warning LNK4204](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4204?view=msvc-170)

> LNK4204 can occur if some of the objects in the library refer to a file that no longer exists. This could happen when rebuilding the solution, for example; an object file might be deleted and not rebuilt because of a compilation error. In this case, either compile with /Z7, or /Fd, to update the objects to refer to a single file per-library (that is not the default .pdb file name). For more information, see /Fd (Program Database File Name). Ensure that the .pdb is saved with the library every time it is updated in the source control system.

Does compiling with /Z7 or /Fd fix this? You can also see this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6181e10e-f695-4f40-a2ca-7f72642469e8/how-to-resolve-warning-lnk4204-?forum=vcgeneral) hope it can help you.

Comment: Yes, compiling with /Z7 fixes the issue as stated in thequestion. The problem is that my coworkers "does not trust" the /Z7 option...